# Display messages in window tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on the following small tkinter application.

The URL & token is for a public development demo which can be found here if interested - https://snipe-it.readme.io/reference#api-overview

My current issue is displaying logging messages to the current tkinter window.
Currently it just prints to the console. I've tried a few different methods but I'm not very good with tkinter at the moment.

I have tried solutions like so - [How do I create a popup window in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946222/how-do-i-create-a-popup-window-in-tkinter) - but this just duplicates the main window each time.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

The csv file looks like so:

```
asset_tag,
1382613192,
1169063140,
785100692,
4565667567345457574535,
```

```
import csv
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

import requests

#todo set initialdir as current user

# initiate logging module
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# set headers are they are used in several functions
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImVmMGVhY2Y4MjAyYzgwZWI2M2JkNmIwZDc0OGYwY2FkYzU2Y2ZlMzgyNzY4ODY0N2EwNmU4ZTBlNmYwZDgwODNjZmMyMzI2YWYyYTZlMTFkIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiZWYwZWFjZjgyMDJjODBlYjYzYmQ2YjBkNzQ4ZjBjYWRjNTZjZmUzODI3Njg4NjQ3YTA2ZThlMGU2ZjBkODA4M2NmYzIzMjZhZjJhNmUxMWQiLCJpYXQiOjE0OTMzMzI2MjgsIm5iZiI6MTQ5MzMzMjYyOCwiZXhwIjoxODA4ODY1NDI4LCJzdWIiOiIyIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.NU7ZRIt-d4b0o8uv9ipo1vSWcg1svbmPp47kHErafm9iuK4FjygKd2_4Hp73HKAmjiYcEn3r39pwNh2t9BMFnTXv0KeDGC8zfZ9z7OJN_a59LPoarWBFzCsYETyAm-CeeFnfdj9Cr0ZeGOnnaPuWPYxicwKFeqJI4Hn8nCymcamDGE0u4WOO95ihGOAen4_fqpj-kkBDsvsGhB-cQxeuKdlbvO1yOsKmgQv-kQuxiFMn1zgU7P02mC6XXrbw6jTm7JOaBSbvqSwNtsrSKZkim1jxLsQ4dm36lFmeMkU6hZvNSUnxg8JwbmoxQ_3tZlG3IJh3Sc9ZUi-AEAQ4bbGzi_xNS9fenIdzLDaSiv_esYyNOYXqOuSBk8Yr-720N9OcVjGLnPrV3RtmPisV1aLFgKWLImtlyQgUq3d5LA3QXz8Q_8isvO9Am1u8ri2plbHGJLJ6GRW_mYcBEYMwUozaeXTUe_FUSSO8gpGtO9Hpa5SbERY272_tojyVXpYPaPdUYYmS9CP332jBNESPT8wGwpOM-iddeVo_n82w3dHmDEdp1Brbs3_vKk0AcgvDLsAbd4dZZO-UqddVx6SDb3HLw1Pmw1wGGYHA6w8wWQAiS9kg2xMcz5i75HOULaN3miqYvcPCvHpI2CBfuvdplI8QNm_XzFPmoQRu_5kR8knzla4",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}


# functions

def check_in(id, asset_tag, headers):
    # check in function, takes the asset ID and POST's to the url
    # can optionally set a checkin note in the payload

    url = "https://develop.snipeitapp.com/api/v1/hardware/"+id+"/checkin"

    # modify if you would like a note with the checkin
    payload = {"note": "checked in by ME"}

    try:
        response = requests.request("POST", url, json=payload, headers=headers)
        checkin_response = response.json()

        '''
        This if statement is required here because if the asset is already checked in, it still returns an http successful message.
        So this checks if the value in the status key is equal to "error" and if so then it will log this as an error.
        '''
        if "error" in checkin_response['status']:
            logging.error("Unable to checkin asset %s - %s"
                          % (asset_tag, checkin_response['messages']))
        else:
            logging.info("Successfully checked in asset %s" % (asset_tag))
            
    # catch any http errors and continue
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        logging.error(e)
        pass

def get_asset_id(asset_tag, output_q, headers):
    # this function gets the asset id from a given asset tag

    url = "https://develop.snipeitapp.com/api/v1/hardware/bytag/"+asset_tag+""

    output_dict = {}

    try:
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        response.raise_for_status()
        json_response = response.json()

        '''
        This checks if the status key exists in the response and if it does then it returns an error.
        This is because the status key does not exist at all in a successful query.
        Again this is required because even if the asset tag doesn't exist, it still returns http 200.
        '''
        if "status" in json_response:
            logging.error("Unable to retrieve asset ID for asset tag %s - %s"
                          % (asset_tag, json_response['messages']))
        else:
            logging.info("Successfully retrieved asset ID from %s" %
                         (asset_tag))
            asset_id = str(json_response['id'])
            check_in(asset_id, asset_tag, headers)

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        logging.error(e)
        pass

    output_q.put(output_dict)

# class for tkinter configuration
class App:


    def __init__(self, master):

        self.label = ttk.Label(master, text="Bulk Checkin")
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
     

        ttk.Button(master, text="Select File",
                   command=self.select_file).grid(row=2, column=0)

        ttk.Button(master, text="Checkin Assets",
                   command=self.checkin_assets).grid(row=2, column=1)

    def select_file(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/fraser/Desktop/", filetypes=(("CSV Files","*.csv"),))
        self.infile = open(filename, "r")
        print(self.infile.name)

    def checkin_assets(self):
        # function for Checkin Assets button click

        # start a timer so we can see how long it takes
        start_time = datetime.now()

        output_q = Queue(maxsize=20)

        procs = []

        with open(self.infile.name, 'r') as myfile:
            csv_reader = csv.DictReader(myfile)
            line_count = 0
            for row in csv_reader:
                if line_count == 0:
                    ", ".join(row)
                    line_count += 1
                line_count += 1
                asset_tag = row["asset_tag"]
                my_proc = Process(target=get_asset_id, args=(
                    asset_tag, output_q, headers))
                my_proc.start()
                procs.append(my_proc)

        # Make sure all processes have finished
        for a_proc in procs:
            a_proc.join()
  
        # log how long this took
        logging.info("\nElapsed time: " + str(datetime.now() - start_time))                

def main():
    main = Tk()
    app = App(main)
    main.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, this is assuming you want the messages as a popup. If not, create your own messaging window, or add a label or something you can update to the main one. I used the two messaging classes from the referenced post, but you can call them from anywhere and pass a message you want displayed.

```
import csv
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo


class App(ttk.Frame):


def __init__(self, master):
    ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

    self.label = ttk.Label(master, text="Bulk Checkin")
    self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
 

    ttk.Button(master, text="Select File",
               command=self.select_file).grid(row=2, column=0)

    ttk.Button(master, text="Checkin Assets",
               command=self.checkin_assets).grid(row=2, column=1) 

def select_file(self):
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/fraser/Desktop/", filetypes=(("CSV Files","*.csv"),))
    self.infile = open(filename, "r")
    print(self.infile.name)

def checkin_assets(self):
    # function for Checkin Assets button click

    # start a timer so we can see how long it takes
    start_time = datetime.now()

    output_q = Queue(maxsize=20)

    procs = []

    with open(self.infile.name, 'r') as myfile:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(myfile)
        line_count = 0
        for row in csv_reader:
            if line_count == 0:
                ", ".join(row)
                line_count += 1
            line_count += 1
            asset_tag = row["asset_tag"]
            my_proc = Process(target=get_asset_id, args=(
                asset_tag, output_q, headers))
            my_proc.start()
            procs.append(my_proc)

    # Make sure all processes have finished
    for a_proc in procs:
        a_proc.join()

    # log how long this took
    logging.info("\nElapsed time: " + str(datetime.now() - start_time))      

def popup_bonus(self, message):
    win = Toplevel()
    win.wm_title("Message")

    l = Label(win, text=message)
    l.grid(row=0, column=0)

    b = ttk.Button(win, text="Ok", command=win.destroy)
    b.grid(row=1, column=0)

def popup_showinfo(self, message):
    showinfo("Message", message)          

def main():
   main = Tk()
   app = App(main)
   main.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I use easygui because it is the simplest and one-liner. **It can work alongside tkinter** so there is no compatibility issues. For example, if you want a messagebox/alert, just do this:

```
import easygui

easygui.msgbox('in cmd, type: "shutdown -a" within 20 seconds', title="Chance to abort shutdown")
```