# How to get input from a tkinter entry box, to a variable in another function?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, input

I am writing a files manager in python. One of the functions is to rename a file. Instead of entering the filename in the terminal with the 'input()' function, I want an input box to pop up so the user can enter the filename in there.

This is the function that renames the file.

```
import os
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox

def rename_file():
    messagebox.showinfo(title="Rename File", message="Select the file you want to rename!")
    renameFileSource = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    if renameFileSource == "":
        messagebox.showinfo(title="File Select Canceled", message="You have canceled the file selection!")
    else:
        try:
            namePath = os.path.dirname(renameFileSource)
            renameFileDestination = os.path.splitext(namePath)[1]
            messagebox.showinfo(title="Rename File", message="Enter the new file name!")
            entry_box()
            if renameFileInput == "":
                messagebox.showinfo(title="No input", message="You have not entered anything!")
            else:
                newPath = os.path.join(namePath, renameFileInput + renameFileDestination)
                os.rename(renameFileSource, newPath)
                messagebox.showinfo(title="File Renamed", message="The file has succesfully been renamed!")
        except OSError as renameFileError:
            messagebox.showerror(title="File Error", message="The following error has occured:\n\n"+ str(renameFileError) + "\n\nPlease try again!")
```

This is the function that has the input box I made with tkinter. I want this function to pass the input to the variable 'renameFileInput' in the 'rename_file()' function

```
def entry_box():
    entryBox = tkinter.Tk()

    def rename_input():
        renameFileInput = entryInput.get()
        entryBox.destroy()

    tkinter.Label(entryBox, text="Enter data here: ").pack()
    entryInput = tkinter.Entry(entryBox)
    entryInput.pack()
    button = tkinter.Button(entryBox, text="GO!", width=3, height=1, command=rename_input)
    button.pack()
    entryBox.mainloop()
```

This is the function that has my main GUI.

```
def gui_window():
    guiWindow = tkinter.Tk()
    tkinter.Label(guiWindow, text="Lucas' Files Manager\n", fg="green", font=("", 40, "normal", "underline")).pack()
    tkinter.Button(guiWindow, text="Rename File", width=25, height=1, bg="blue", fg="red", font=("", "20", "bold"), command=rename_file).pack()
    tkinter.Button(guiWindow, text="Exit Program", width=25, height=1, bg="blue", fg="red", font=("", "20", "bold"), command=guiWindow.destroy).pack()
    guiWindow.mainloop()

gui_window()
```

When I run the code as shown above, I get the following error: NameError: name 'renameFileInput' is not defined.

I have uploaded the code to my entire files manager to github: https://github.com/GierLucas/File-Manager

Comment: Can you add the exact error you get? (including ine of the error) Seems you are messing with the scopes of the functions.

Comment: yes, this is the excact error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\lucas\Desktop\Python Projects\File Manager\file manager test.py", line 17, in rename_file
    if renameFileInput == "":
NameError: name 'renameFileInput' is not defined
PS C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\Python Projects\File Manager>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that your program is trying to acces the variable `renameFileInput` before it creates it, so a `NameError` exception is raised. From the code you linked ([here](https://github.com/GierLucas/File-Manager/blob/main/File%20manager%202.py)), you define that variable in the function  `rename_input` (which is inside of `entry_box`) and try to use it in the function `rename_file`.

The problem is that the variable created in `rename_input` is destroyed when the function ends, that is when its scope ends. To get the rest of the code know that value you have a few options. The recommended is to `return` that value, so you can transfer it to the scope where that function was called. The other option is to make that variable a `global` variable. This means that variable can be accessed in every part of your code.

To globalize a variable in a scope, type `global <variable>` at the start of the function, in your case:

```
def entry_box():
    entryBox = tkinter.Tk()
    def callback():
        global renameFileInput
        renameFileInput = entryInput.get()
        print(renameFileInput)
        entryBox.destroy()
    tkinter.Label(entryBox, text="Enter data here: ").pack()
    entryInput = tkinter.Entry(entryBox)
    entryInput.pack()
    btn = tkinter.Button(entryBox, text="GO!", width=3, height=1, command=callback)
    btn.pack()
    entryBox.mainloop()
```

This should solve the problem you state, although your code has more errors, starting from that `mainloop` you have in that method. It will not let you keep  the application as you would expect.

#### Further information

To create popup windows better use `TopLevel` class. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946222/how-do-i-create-a-popup-window-in-tkinter) a related question.

About [scopes](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/#:%7E:text=In%20Python%2C%20the%20concept%20of,dictionaries%20are%20commonly%20called%20namespaces.)

About return in functions, see [here](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/)

Comment: Making the variable a global variable solved the problem indeed, thank you very much!  As you already state in your answer, the code has more errors (it's the first program i'm attempting to make). After I input a filename and press 'GO', I want the next line of code to execute, however, I need to close my program (gui_window) first for it to work. So I will read the documentation from the links you included and try for a further solution. I'm guessing it has to do with the mainloop indeed. I will try TopLevel class for a pop up window. Thanks again for the solution and the links provided!